# Java Collections Comparable wrong 3rd argument type in Collections.binarySearch()

Tags: java

I am trying to use *Binary search* using `Collections.binarySearch();`

I need to compared based on `mId` field of the `Item` .

**The compilation error is:**

> Found 'java.util.comparator'  Required 'java.util.comparator < ?
>   super java.lang.comparable < ? extends java.lang.comparable < ?
>   extends java.lang.comparable < ? >>>>'

```
public class SomeOuterClass {
public static class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    static long id = 0;
    public Boolean isSaved;
    public Boolean isLoved;

    long mId;
    Post post;

    public Item(Post p) {
        mId = id++;
        post = p;
        isSaved = Boolean.FALSE;
        isLoved = Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return Comparators.ID.compare(this, o);
    }


    public static class Comparators {
        public static Comparator<Item> TITLE = new Comparator<Item>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
                return o1.post.title().compareTo(o2.post.title());
            }
        };
        public static Comparator<Item> ID = new Comparator<Item>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
                return (int) (-(o1.mId - o2.mId));//I am putting a minus to indicate list is in descending order
            }
        };
    }

}

private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

public Item findByBinSrach(int itemId) {
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(items, itemId, Item.Comparators.ID);//Here it is not recognizing the 3rd parameter
    return getItem(index);
}}
```

Comment: `(int) (-(o1.mId - o2.mId))` would be better written as `Long.compare(o2.mId, o1.mId)`, to avoid overflow and casting.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter should be the `Item` you are looking for, *not* its `itemId`. `Collections.binarySearch` has no way of knowing how to relate an `int` to an `Item`.

You might find it easier to store `items` as a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Item>` (if you require insertion order to be preserved; you can use `HashMap` if you don't care about order), where the key is the `itemId`. Then, you can simply use `return items.get(itemId)`.

Two other points:

1. It is generally a bad idea to have side effects in constructors (in this case, incrementing `id`): it makes testing (amongst other things) hard. It would be better to inject the `mId` as a constructor parameter;
2. Make `mId` final, in order that it can't be changed post-construction - this is especially relevant if you adopt the `Map` suggestion above, since you wouldn't want the map key to be different to the value returned.